# Add contextual (or arbitrary) map insets with ggmap in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, geospatial, ggmap

Good day,

Let's say I use `library(ggmap)` in R to make this map:

```
ggmap(get_map(location = c(lon = -81.38630, lat = 19.30340), source = "stamen", maptype = "terrain", zoom = 14))
```

Which gives:

[image]

How do I add a small contextual inset map to this image (probably near the top left?) to show the wider geographical area? In this small inset I'd like for it to have a box that outlines where the bigger map fits in.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible solution based on the use of `grid` viewports.

```
library(ggmap)
library(grid)

map1 <- get_map(location = c(lon = -81.38630, lat = 19.30340), 
        maptype = "terrain", zoom = 14)
map2 <- get_map(location = c(lon = -81.38630, lat = 19.30340), 
        maptype = "terrain", zoom = 12)

p1 <- ggmap(map1)
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
grid.draw(g1)

pushViewport( viewport(x=0.25, y=0.8, w=.3, h=.3) )
xy <- data.frame(x=c(-81.41,-81.41,-81.36,-81.36,-81.41), 
       y=c(19.33,19.28,19.28,19.33,19.33))
p2 <- ggmap(map2) + 
      geom_path(data=xy, aes(x,y), color="red", lwd=1) + 
      theme_void()
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)
grid.draw(g2)
grid.rect(gp=gpar(col="white", lwd=5))
popViewport()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! This basically worked for me, however it drew on top of my existing plots (from before I made the plot). Is there a way to start a completely new plot then run this code?

Comment: @hpy Nice to help you! To open a new page, try `grid.newpage` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grid/versions/3.4.1/topics/grid.newpage

Comment: Ah I see, OK I'll remember to use `grid.newpage()`. Thanks again!

Comment: BTW, I discovered the `cowplot` package which might be able to achieve this, too: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html